# Whats wrong with this error? Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token

Tags: java, syntax-error, token

I have this line of code in my Java program:

```
private final List<PhoneNumber> receivers = new ArrayList<>();
```

It signifies an error underneath the first **<** after 'new ArrayList'.             ^

I'm running Eclipse and Windows 8 - 32-bit, could this be an encoding problem?

Comment: what version of java are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: You have to parametarize the type of object at both sides.

```
private final List<PhoneNumber> receivers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
```

Comment: Since Java 7, you can also do : `private final List<PhoneNumber> receivers = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @AchintyaJha http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Comment: @ZouZou I viewed it already . My java version is 1.7.0_17. But it shows eerror. Dont know why.

Comment: This is a workaround, but not a fix, since we're working in a team. I need to have it working without adding 'PhoneNumber' between the Diamond Operator..

Answer (score 1):

The [Diamond Operator](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7567), used to reduce the verbosity when using generics was added in JDK 1.7. The fact you're getting a syntax error probably means you're using an older version to compile this piece of code.

Either use JDK 1.7 to compile the code, or change to:

```
new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me:

- Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Compiler Compliance Level: 1.7

this was 1.6 at first.

Had to download Eclipse Indigo RS2 for this one.